# Front-end web UI implementation of Apache Mesos

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I am wondering how `Apache Mesos` implements the front-end web ui (`localhost:port`) in which users can track the system's current status and the submitted jobs. Is there any library for this? How does `Mesos` do this (in C++)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, having a look at the source code reveals what it's using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="mesos">
  <head>
    ...
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-3.3.6.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/underscore-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/zeroclipboard-1.1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/angular-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/angular-route-1.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

So, it's using

- Angular
- jQuery
- Bootstrap